# Picasso - callback that indicates loaded bitmap from web

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I want to set a callback that triggers when the image is loaded from web. I know using of fetch

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL).fetch(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    imageView.setAlpha(0f);
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL).into(imageView);
                    imageView.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(1f).start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                }
            });
```

But I don't use upper implementation. I want to get a bitmap and change it, then show into image view.

I expect that target works for my case. But onBitmapLoaded doesn't trigger many times. I don't understand why.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation is that the `Target` instances you are creating are garbage collected before being used, because they are not strongly referenced anywhere. From [`RequestCreator.into()`](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-com.squareup.picasso.Target-) javadoc :

> Note: This method keeps a weak reference to the Target instance and
>   will be garbage collected if you do not keep a strong reference to it.

You could keep a strong reference in the `ViewHolder` or in the view (so that it will collected only if the view is also collected)

For example (in the view) :

```
    Target target = new Target() {
        ...
    };

    // strong reference from the view
    imageView.setTag(target);

    // weak reference
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL).into(target);
```

Comment: into method doesn't return a bitmap before load into image view. How can I pre-process the image?

Comment: Maybe the first thing to to do is to check if the explanation is correct, I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with Glide you could solve your problem?

```
    Glide.with(this)
        .load(URL)
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean =
                        false

                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    imageView.alpha = 0F
                    imageView.animate().alpha(1F).setDuration(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(2000)).start()
                    return false
                }

        })
        .into(imageView)
```

(If I understand you correct...)